# Enabling WMSVC access over IPv6

Tags: iis, iis-7

The IIS Management Service configuration IP Address restriction user interface only allows entry of IPv4 addresses.

Unlike IIS websites, however, WMSVC stores it's configuration in the registry (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WebManagement\Server`). This includes a base64 encoded binary representation of `RemoteRestrictions`, making it pretty much impossible to modify it.

Is my only choice to allow by default?

Answer (score 1):

The obvious workaround is to install an IPv6-capable firewall (e.g. Comodo, ZoneAlarm) on the server.

You could also try configuring it to allow access by domain, rather than by IP address ranges.

Of course if you have Server 2003 then you have absolutely no business running IPv6 on that thing at all; the IPv6 stack wasn't ready for production use and MS never updated it for XP/2003.

Comment: I'm running IIS7 + Server 2008 R2. Also the traffic is all internal.